# Extracting Dynamics 365 data using Azure Data Factory pipeline with FetchXML query

Tags: azure-data-factory, dynamics-365, fetchxml

I want to use FetchXML query to extract data from Dynamics 365 in Azure Data Factory.

I used this initial setup for the entity 'campaignactivity' (without any FetchXML query):
[image]

And in preview data I see columns like actualstart:
[image]

But when I tried using FetchXML query, I got this error:
[image]

This is the FetchXML query I am using:
[image]

I tried testing it with only one attribute but I only get the primary key as output:
[image]
[image]

I tried this pipeline with other entities too. Some of them don't produce any error but it also has fewer columns than not using FetchXML query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's some issue parsing the text you gave. I've got it to work using single quotes or text functions like `@concat()`.

This is a fetch that i use for the contact entity for example:

```
concat('<fetch><entity name="contact"><filter type="and"><condition attribute="contactid" operator="eq" value="{', $DataverseFhirId,'}"/></filter></entity></fetch>')
```

And here is another without `@concat`, make sure to use single quotes:

```
'<fetch><entity name="contact"><attribute name="parentcustomerid" /><attribute name="drh_patientfhirid" /></entity></fetch>'
```

Also, for some reason if you dont specify any attributes, it fetches the whole entity.